# What positional play strategy should white adopt when fighting against the Philidor exchange variation?

Tags: opening, positional-play, philidor-defense

What are the key squares to control? What are ultra aggressive moves white can play at the advance level (expert or higher class)?

Comment: By coincidence, yesterday, Vachier-Lagrave won a game with white against Rapport, who used the Philidor exchange variation: http://en.chessbase.com/post/biel-final-mvl-wins-again

Comment: I agree with Joe's answer. The Philidor is a pretty solid opening, and you will probably not find a hyper-aggressive reply that is great, because otherwise it would already be common knowledge. But it's not an ambitious setup by black, so as white you don't really need to worry about going for the kill from move 1.

Answer (score 2):

Why not follow that game? - he got a nice centralised position with pressure on d6.
 No need to take risks with "Ultra-aggressive" moves.